# How to compare column 2 and 3 of File 1 and column 4 and 5 of file 2

Tags: text-processing, awk, python, bioinformatics

I have a tab delimited file 1:

```
NC_025345       4569   4950   KX838946.2      
NC_025345       16546   17066   KJ641660.1      
NC_025345       11996   12085   KX932454.2
```

And file 2:

```
NC_025345.1     RefSeq  gene    5690    7513    .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp4;Dbxref=GeneID:20964334;Name=NZ82_gp4;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=NZ82_gp4
NC_025345.1     RefSeq  gene    8016    10046   .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp5;Dbxref=GeneID:20964335;Name=NZ82_gp5;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=NZ82_gp5
NC_025345.1     RefSeq  gene    10337   16933   .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp6;Dbxref=GeneID:20964336;Name=NZ82_gp6;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=NZ82_gp6
```

I want to compare column 2 and 3 of file 1 with column 4 and 5 of file 2. If column 2 and 3 of file 1 overlaps or falls in-between column 4 and 5 of file 2, I want to combine the whole line of file 1 and file 2 into a new file to give output like this:

```
NC_025345       11996   12085   KX932454.2     NC_025345.1     RefSeq  gene    10337   16933   .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp6;Dbxref=GeneID:20964336;Name=NZ82_gp6;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=NZ82_gp6
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help. How do I go about a situation where I want to consider column1 of file 1 should match column1 of file 2 while column 2 of file 1 is >= column 4 of file2 and column 3 is <= column5 of file2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient `awk` script:

```
awk '{
  if (NR==FNR) {
    l[NR]=$0
    a[NR]=$2
    b[NR]=$3
  }
  else if (a[FNR]>=$4 && b[FNR]<=$5) {
    print l[FNR],$0
  }
}' file1 file2 > newfile
```

When the first file is read (`NR==FNR`), save the whole line `$0` and fields `$2` and `$3` in arrays at index `NR` (record number). When the second file is read, compare the values in array `a` and `b` at given index `FNR` (record number of the file) with fields `$4` and `$5`.

If the array values are in range, print the old line and the current line.
The output is written to a new file `newfile`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How do I go about a situation where I want to consider column1 of file 1 should match column1 of file 2 while column 2 of file 1 is >= column 4 of file2 and column 3 is <= column5 of file2

Comment: You would have to add one more array variable for column1 to the if-condition (`c[NR]=$1`) and one more comparison to the else-condition (`c[FNR]==$1 && …`) assuming that file1 and file2 are sorted on column1 and we can directly compare column1 in lineX of file1 with column1 in lineX of file2.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $f1=shift;
open(F1,"<",$f1) || die "Couldn't open $f1: $!\n";

my $f2=shift;
open(F2,"<",$f2) || die "Couldn't open $f2: $!\n";

until (eof(F1) || eof(F2)) {
  my @a = split /\t/,<F1>;
  my @b = split /\t/,<F2>;
  chomp($a[@a-1]);

  # note: perl arrays start from 0, not 1
  print join("\t",@a, @b) if (($a[1] >= $b[3]) && ($a[2] <= $b[4]));
}
```

This opens the two filename arguments as file-handles `F1` and `F2` respectively.  If either file fails to open, it exits with an error message.

Then, while neither of them has reached EOF (end-of-file), it:

- reads a line at a time from each file-handle into separate arrays (`@a` for F1 and `@b` for F2).

  The `chomp()` function removes the trailing newline character (`\n`) from the last element of array `@a`, to prevent a newline from appearing in the middle of any output lines where the arrays are joined.
- If the arrays meet your criteria ($a[1]>=$b[3], and $a[2]<=$b[4]), it prints both arrays as one output line, joined with tabs as field separators.

Save it as, e.g. `ibk.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x ibk.pl` and run it as:

```
$ ./ibk.pl file1 file2 
NC_025345       11996   12085   KX932454.2      NC_025345.1     RefSeq  gene    10337   16933   .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp6;Dbxref=GeneID:20964336;Name=NZ82_gp6;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=NZ82_gp6
```

Comment: Can you explain how the script works?

Comment: @ibk explanation added. and script simplified slightly (only the final element of @a needed to be chomped).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How do I go about a situation where I want to consider column1 of file 1 should match column1 of file 2 while column 2 of file 1 is >= column 4 of file2 and column 3 is <= column5 of file2

Comment: by making those exact comparisons with the elements of the @a and @b arrays, remembering that perl arrays start from an index of 0 rather than 1.   Use the `if` statement in my answer as an example that can be modified as needed for different criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can doit as follows : first paste the files together, then run awk to filter out the desired lines.

```
$ nf1=$(<file1 awk '{print NF;exit}') 

$ paste file1 file2 | awk -vnf1="$nf1" '$(4+nf1)<=$2 && $3<=$(5+nf1)'
```